# Как я могу на этапе инициализации передать и использовать credentials в файл settings.gradle

Tags: docker, gradle, jenkins

Credentials находятся в nexus и вариант использования gradle.properties мне не походит.
На данный момент у меня есть:

```
 settings.gradle file
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
      maven {
        url = uri("my url")
        credentials {
          username credentials.getProperty("Login")
          password credentials.getProperty("Password")            
         }
 }
```

Я ожидаю что при импорте плагинов определенных в build.gradle я буду идти по адресу "my url" а логин и пароль будет браться из контейнера credentials
Я добавляю credentials следующим образом:

```
RUN ./gradlew addCredentials --key Login --value $USERNAME --no-scan && \
   ./gradlew addCredentials --key Password --value $PASSWORD  --no-scan
```

в своем docker файле

Подскажи пожалуйста как я могу использовать credentials на уровне settings.gradle?

Comment: Через переменные окружения передавать не вариант?

Comment: Нет через переменные окружения нельзя